# Doubt about half adder timing

Tags: adder

In my book there is the architecture of a basic circuit with a half adder with 1 AND and 1 XOR for the carry, and a "maimed" half adder with one XOR for the previous carry. Then book say that minimum time of an operation is $$t_{min}=t_{xor} $$ (without carry) and the max time is $$t_{max} = t_{xor} + t_{and}$$ but the max time should not be $$t_{max} = 2t_{xor} + t_{and}$$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the top XOR is **not** an input to the logic that generates D1, so the delay through the top XOR does not contribute to the delay from Q0 and Q1 to D1.

Answer (score 0):

Your "maimed" circuit makes no sense at all. A half-adder is just two gates:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ4SWN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A full adder combines two half-adders and an OR gate to handle carry-in and generate carry-out:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbJ1kN.png)</sup>

If for some reason you wanted a circuit that had a carry-in but no carry-out, you'd simply eliminate all of the AND and OR gates:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKYFi5.png)</sup>

There is no configuration that has an XOR gate following any AND or OR gate.

Comment: The circuit was written by my professor of Electronics, I thought that it was right.